# 3G modem keeps resetting

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, 3g

I have a new USB 3G modem that keeps re-appearing as a new device, i.e. the device is disconnected from Windows, then appears as a new device again, with the autorun popup appearing. Of course this means I keep losing my 3G connection as well. Is there anything I can do about this before I go and try to exchange the device?

I have been advised it might be a USB power problem, but this condition isn't constant; I can use the modem for hours on end without problems, then at random times the bloody thing starts acting up and does it's reappearing trick every few seconds when it's bad.

Comment: If you've tried multiple different USB ports, then it sounds broken.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely this problem is related to Windows automatically powering down USB ports/devices. I have disabled this wherever I could find anything, i.e. device manager and power settings, and I have since enjoyed uninterrupted use of my 3G modem for ten hours today. Unfortunately I can't report on exactly which setting solved the problem.